# RDS RemoteApp Disconnected

Tags: rdp, rds, windows-server-2019, remoteapp

I have a small pre-production environment build on Server 2019 Datacenter. There are two brokers, one gateway, one collection with two desktop servers and six collections with single server for applications. After installation everything worked well, I could run remoteapp published via app servers from desktops. I have published many apps. After some time all apps from one of the app servers has stopped working.

Error message is "Remoteapp Disconnected. This computer can't connect to the remote computer. Try connecting again. If the problem continues, contact the owner of the remote computer or your network administrator."

It does not work for every user. I have tried publish new app from the same collection and it does not work too. Apps from other collections work without problems.

I had to unpublish apps, remove collection and then create it again. This helped, all apps works. Now after a while the same problem occurs on other server.

I did not do any changes in GPOs, neither other config changes (firewall etc.).

I did not found reason in logs.

Could you please give me an advice?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the server?

Comment: of course. it was the first try. it did not help.

Comment: OK. You might want to put that detail in your question. It's not a given that we would assume that.

Comment: While unable to connect to remoteapp, are you able to connect to the server's desktop with RDP ?

Comment: yes, desktop via rdp is still working.